# Reproducing f.lux's warm colors

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, rgb

I'm an avid [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) user and have been for a while. Whenever I'm working on a design, I do it during the day so the yellow tint doesn't ruin my color schemes at night thanks to f.lux. However, I have accidentally found colors that I really like while using f.lux but obviously, when I disable f.lux, the color is entirely different.

For what it's worth, I'm using photoshop but this would apply to any RGB values. How would I reproduce the color I'm seeing with f.lux enabled? I have found the following links through my research but I don't know enough about colors to be able to use this information and would appreciate any help.

- https://techblog.jeppson.org/2014/12/manually-reproduce-flux-monitor/
- http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/blackbody/

Comment: Many of the color management systems can be calibrated to similar needs but based on real surrounding lightning, on bonus side they would automatically make a color profile for you. It certainly is possible to make a color conversion between these but its a bit involved-